# How can I pythonically print and write the same string (two operations on one object)

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.x

I'm currently doing this but I feel like there would be a cleaner way to do this, as I'm editing the code to write to a file everything that it prints. Is there a one-liner or something more concise for the following? Thanks

```
print 'foo bar'
file.write('foo bar')
```

Comment: No, there is no easy one-liner; unless this is logging code, in which case you wanted to use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead and add in multiple handlers. If not, just write a function.

Comment: Use a logger with [multiple destinations](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations).

Comment: If you don't want to use `logging` (but you really should…), you probably want to make the two more similar by using either `print` and `print >>file`, or `sys.stdout.write` and `file.write`. Otherwise, you're going to get things that don't work the same in the two cases. For example, `print` works with multiple arguments, non-string arguments, etc., while `write` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file-like object that writes to a number of other files:

```
class Tee(object):
    """A file-like that writes to all the file-likes it has."""

    def __init__(self, *files):
        """Make a Tee that writes to all the files in `files.`"""
        self._files = files

    def write(self, data):
        """Write `data` to all the files."""
        for f in self._files:
            f.write(data)
```

Then you can create a Tee object:

```
tee = Tee(sys.stdout, file)
```

and write to your tee:

```
tee.write(data)
```

and the output will go to the file and to stdout.

Comment: Or `print >>tee, data`, if he wants the `print` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's as good as you're going to get<sup>1</sup> -- Of course, if you want it in one line, you could wrap it up in a function . . .

```
def print_and_write(fileobj, data):
    print data
    fileobj.write(data)
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>For general purpose code.  For the specific case of logging, you might do a little better using the logging module as others have pointed out in the comments</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is logging in any form, then use a logger with [multiple destinations](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations).
In your case, a [`StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) directed to `sys.stdout`, and a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) for logging to a file:

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('out.log'))     # log to file
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))  # log to stdout

logger.info('foo bar')
```

Requires a bit of setup, but after that this solution is as clean as it gets, IMHO. And thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import sys

outfile = open("test.txt",'w')

[print("foo bar",file = i) for i in [outfile,sys.stdout]]

outfile.close()
```